# How to create a UTC datetime object in py2?

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

I have to add legacy support for py2. In py3, I can do something like

```
dt = datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 28, 12, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.UTC)
```

I don't think this works in py3 b/c `datetime.timezone` is a py3 artifact. How can this be done in py2? I think there's a way to do it with `pytz`, although ideally, I would like to do it upon construction like in the py3 semantics.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this without using `pytz` is to define your own `tzinfo` subclass, similar to [how it is done in the official docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.tzinfo):

```py
import datetime

class UTC(datetime.tzinfo):
    def utcoffset(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(0)

    def tzname(self, dt):
        return "UTC"

    def dst(self, dt):
        return datetime.timedelta(0)
```

Use this UTC class to create a timezone-aware datetime object:

```py
utc = UTC()
dt = datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 28, 12, tzinfo=utc)
```

Although it is probably easier to just use `pytz`:

```py
import pytz


dt = datetime.datetime(2023, 11, 28, 12, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
```

You can also refer to the Python 3 implementation of `datetime.timezone.UTC`: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.12/Lib/_pydatetime.py#L2440